# Using a shared library class from a custom step with Jenkins pipeline shared libraries

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I am setting up a shared library for Jenkins pipelines and am trying to figure out how to import a class in the shared library into a custom step that I am writing.

Here's what the directory structure looks like:

```
src
--jenny
----util
------Versioning.groovy
vars
--calculateVersion.groovy
```

The Versioning.groovy file defines some static helper methods that do some stuff.

```groovy
package jenny.util
class Versioner implements Serializable {
    static bool checkForValidVersion(version) {
        return true
    }
}
```

I would like to call this method from the `calculateVersion.groovy` something like this:

```groovy
def call(version) {
    return jenny.util.Versioner.checkForValidVersion(version)
}
```

So that my declarative pipeline can call:
    `def valid = calculateVersion "1.0.0"`

But I receive this error `No such property: jenny for class: calculateReleaseVersions`

Is it possible to reference the classes in the shared library from files in the vars to define custom steps and how is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. At least for us:

Just like in plain java (or groovy) we put an import statement into the groovy script in `vars`. In your case that would be something like:

```
import jenny.util.Versioner

def call(version) {
    return Versioner.checkForValidVersion(version)
}
```

Another thing I just found: It looks like the file name of the class `Versioner` doesn't match the class name: `Versioning.groovy`. Could that be the issue?

If that doesn't work you propably want to upgrade your pipeline plugin version(s).

Comment: Thanks for the response, both of those were issues for me.